# What is the quartz default thread count

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am new to `Quartz`. I did manage to figure out that default value for Scheduler configuration is `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=-1`.

But it did not find anywhere what this implies. Does this mean that there will be only one thread or has it some other 'number'?

I am playing with quartz-scheduler v2.2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends..

If you use `Spring Framework` then you can see that the real default is defined in [SchedulerFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html):

```
public static final int DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT = 10;
```

In case of using bare `Quartz` and and not passing any property, it will use its default configuration, which you can find it in `org.quartz.properties:quartz` jar. It's called `quartz.properties` [(here's link)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.0/org/quartz/quartz.properties?av=f) and contains:

```
# Default Properties file for use by StdSchedulerFactory
# to create a Quartz Scheduler Instance, if a different
# properties file is not explicitly specified.
#

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export: false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy: false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction: false

org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

So, it's **10** in the most cases.

On the other hand, if you just wanted to create `SimpleThreadPool` without specyfying thread-pool size, it will throw exception from `initialize` method as ([here's link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.0/org/quartz/simpl/SimpleThreadPool.java?av=f#241)):

```
if (count <= 0) {
    throw new SchedulerConfigException(
            "Thread count must be > 0");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to start `Quartz` with default value `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=-1`

It doesn't start. You got `org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Thread count must be > 0`

The default `-1` value force you to config `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` to your value more then 0 .

From [jdoc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool)

> **org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount**
>
> Can be any positive integer...

Comment: you did answer what it wanted but Maciej's answer was exactly what I wanted to know,  Thanks any way.