# Batch job is not executing

Tags: java, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz & Spring Batch framework and scheduled almost 84 jobs. I have noticed recently that some of the jobs are not executing at all when above 80 jobs are scheduled to run.

If I schedule around 30 jobs then each jobs are executing on time and found no issue.

Not sure how to track down the root cause but i believe it could be the issue of unavailability of thread to each jobs. Any idea to sort out this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the number of threads:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 100
```

Look this post for default thread number: [What is the quartz default thread count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723948/what-is-the-quartz-default-thread-count)

Comment: Little improvement on execution but many jobs are not executing as its scheduled time. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you post your trigger and job configuration?